# Can I rent the house that I currently paying to own?

Tags: real-estate

I'm just wondering if it is legal or are there law that prohibits it, since I plan to buy a house and rented it out to someone so that they are the ones who will pay the house for me and I'm the one getting the ownership of it onces it is agreement is done.

Comment: Please specify the country. Any question that asks "is it legal?" has to include the jurisdiction.

Comment: Your rental agreement might say something about this.

Answer (score 9):

The specifics of the law vary with where you are, so please comment or edit to indicate your jurisdiction. Typically it is possible to do this but the mortgage lender definitely needs to know that this is the plan (and you may need a larger deposit and/or get a more expensive rate). In the UK these are called "buy to let" mortgages and I believe they are called "buy to rent" in the US.

Not directly what you asked, but you also need to remember to factor in the cost of gaps between tenants (when you have to cover the mortgage yourself) and repairs and maintenance etc when you are calculating how to set the rent.

Answer (score 0):

You can buys house. If you don’t have enough cash, you’ll have to go to a bank and get a mortgage that you have to pay back with interest.

Once you own the house, you can rent it out. You’ll use the rent to pay for repairs, taxes etc. and to pay for the mortgage. If the person renting it decides to move out and you don’t find another renter, you don’t get rent but still have to pay the mortgage.

The renter never pays for the house; they pay rent that you use to pay off the mortgage. All in all you need to be organised, it’s work, and can be costly if you do things wrong.

Comment: As mentioned above, the mortgage lender needs to be informed of the intention to rent out. When getting a mortgage, one must be honest about intentions for the property or risk being accused of occupancy fraud. If one already has an owner-occupant mortgage and wants to rent out the home, one may be able to discuss it with the mortgage lender. Some lenders will permit renting out on existing rate and terms. Others may charge a fee, require waiting a certain amount of time, or require refinance.